# Managing commands in a child frame Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, command, parent-child

I'm using the following functions to open a input dialogue from a menu in Tkinter.

```
def show_entry_fields(e):
    global pwd 
    pwd = e.get()

def showPwdInputBox():
    # display an input box for the password
    c = Toplevel(root)
    c.title("Enter your password")
    c.geometry('200x160+230+130')
    Label(c, text="Password").pack() #(row=0)
    e1 = Entry(c, show="*")

    e1.pack()

    Button(c, text='OK', command= lambda: show_entry_fields(e1)).pack()
    Button(c, text='Close', command=c.destroy).pack()
```

I need the dialogue to be closed when the user presses OK. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the function to do more than one thing, simply make an ordinary function instead of using a `lambda`:

```
def ok_command():
    show_entry_fields(e1)
    c.destroy()

Button(c, text='OK', command=ok_command).pack()
```

However, I would recommend saving separate references to each widget and not chaining your geometry management, as you can't reference widgets that have had their geometry management method chained onto them. Even if you don't plan to reference these particular widgets at this particular time, it's a good practice to cultivate.

```
ok_button = Button(c, text='OK', command=ok_command)
ok_button.pack()
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Would anyone care to explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: Friend, 
because I don't care about scoring.

Comment: @SDilmac: are you saying you downvoted this question become someone downvoted your question?

Comment: @BryanOakley 
No Sir,
I don't have time to hate (the important thing is to develop and to contribute).
I have no idea about the scoring.
From this site, so I took advantage (still I'm taking advantage of).
He's my friend, I will always remain so.
if my friend is upset, that's why I'm sorry.